# how do linux scheduler classes communicate with each other

Tags: c, linux

I'm recently reading code of linux kernel 2.6.26.5 and trying to implement another scheduler class. However, I'm confused with how linux kernel deals with the communication between different scheduler classes. 
For example, in sched_rt.c, rt_sched_class is defined as:

```
static const struct sched_class rt_sched_class = {
    .next               = &fair_sched_class,
    .enqueue_task       = enqueue_task_rt,
    .dequeue_task       = dequeue_task_rt,
    .yield_task         = yield_task_rt,
#ifdef CONFIG_SMP
    .select_task_rq     = select_task_rq_rt,
#endif /* CONFIG_SMP */ 
......
```

field "next" is pointing to the next sched_class, which is fair_sched_class here.

I'm confused with how it gets to know what is fair_sched_class. As fair_sched_class is defined in another file shed_fair.c, I would suppose there is an include or something that "tell" rt_sched_class what is fair_sched_class.

However, I searched the whole file but can't find "include" in sched_rt.c at all. So I'm wondering how it works, why we can get value of fair_sched_class in sched_rt.c?
   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`$LINUX/kernel/sched/rt.c` includes `sched.h`, which contains several `extern` forward declarations for the scheduler class instance variables:

```
extern const struct sched_class stop_sched_class;
extern const struct sched_class rt_sched_class;
extern const struct sched_class fair_sched_class;
extern const struct sched_class idle_sched_class;
```

The actual definitions of the variables are then spread out over the scheduler compilation units (.c files).

Also there's no communication taking place, this is just a single linked list with initializers defined at compile time.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your help! but the code you posted seems come from newer version of linux. I'm working on linux 2.26.5 and there is no include in sched_rt.c ..

Comment: @Dumpling: Just look for some `extern` forward declarations, telling the compiler, what's available from other compilation units.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much! I finally figured out why. The sched_rt.c file is not compiled individually. It is included in sched.c together with  sched_fair.c . So when the compiler compiles sched.c, the variables exist : )

Answer (score 0):

Better look at [kernelnewbies](http://kernelnewbies.org) or check out [LWN](http://lwn.net)'s coverage of scheduler development. It is a *very* complex area, and the code changes rapidly. I.e., talk to the experts, not to us bloody amateurs.

Comment: lol thanks to your suggestion! I'm also new to linux...It's my Operating system course assignment. Soooo hard..